# How to configure artifact store of mlflow tracking service to connect to minio S3 using minio STS generated acces_key, secret_key and session_token

Tags: amazon-s3, minio, mlflow, mlops

- Minio is configured with LDAP and am generating credentials of user
  with AssumeRoleWithLDAPIdentity using STS API ([reference](https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/security/ad-ldap-external-identity-management/AssumeRoleWithLDAPIdentity.html#assumerolewithldapidentity))
- From above values, I'm setting the variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN ([reference](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#amazon-s3-and-s3-compatible-storage))

I'm getting error when am trying to push model to mlflow to store in minio artifact

```
S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload /tmp/tmph68xubhm/model/MLmodel to mlflow/1/xyz/artifacts/model/MLmodel: An error occurred (InvalidTokenId) when calling the PutObject operation: The security token included in the request is invalid
```